# Changing the wordpress uploads default directory structure

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress uploads folder is structured in the default way (year/month)

I have successfully changed the uploads directory location.

But the problem is that I have 10000+ posts and I am looking for a solution so that I can also move the existing medias to the the new location.

I know doing this will also require me to change the path of the medias at the database level.

Does any one know any plugin or script for doing so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different options mentioned [here](https://blog.templatetoaster.com/update-old-urls-in-database/), most of them are either using an already configured plugin, or running SQL scripts.

Most useful answer that was on that link that I found involved changing the old URLs found on each wp table in your MySQL database

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'Existing URL', 'New URL') 
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'Existing URL', 'New URL');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'Existing URL','New URL');

UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'Existing URL','New URL');

UPDATE wp_links SET link_url = replace(link_url, 'Existing URL','New URL');

UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = replace(comment_content , 'Existing 
URL','New URL');
```

And keep in mind the MySQL replace command can replace part of the URL string, it doesn't have to replace the entire URL string. So in your case, if the original url was
'http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/img.jpg' you could replace the URL as

```
UPDATE wp_links set link_url = replace(link_url, 'http://yourdomain.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2010/10/', 'http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/') where 
link_url like 'http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/%'
```

You would have to do this for each year and month, but scripting it out this way would be a lot easier than manually updating every URL!